# carrierwave manipulation, model.attribute nil in image uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, image-processing, imagemagick, carrierwave

I am manipulating the resize/fill of image based on usage_tag field. A location can have many images.
The issue is images not got resized. When i am raising model to yaml, it shows nil for every field.

Answer asap :(.

in my ImageUploader

```
process :scale

  def scale
    manipulate! do |img|
      raise model.to_yaml
      if model.usage_tag == "logo"
        #raise model.to_yaml
        img.resize_to_fill!(320,320)
      elsif model.usage_tag == "thumbnail"
        img.resize_to_fill!(200,200)
      else
        img.resize_to_fill!(640,720)
      end
      img
    end
  end
```

And below is the form :

```
    <%= form_for([:admin,@location]) do |f| %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :state %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :state %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :country %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :country %>
    </div>
    <div class="images">
      <%= f.fields_for :location_images do |f2| %>
          <div class="field">
            <%= f2.file_field :image %>

            <%= f2.object.usage_tag if f2.object.usage_tag %>
            <%= f2.text_field :usage_tag %>
            <%#= deal_image.check_box :_destroy %>
          </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than putting the condition inside the process block you could create version for each type and use the version :if option to do the condition.

https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Do-conditional-processing

Comment: But I do not want to waste the space by creating version and keep original files as well.
I only want one image that is cropped as per usage_tag, logo, thumb or default.